# How to add numbers if numbers are input using a user-defined function

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Is it possible to add integers if they are inputted using a user-defined function? Here is my sample code below

```
def first_num(num1):
    num1 = int(input("Enter first number: "))
    return 

def sec_num(num2):
    num2 = int(input("Enter second number: "))
    return 

print("ARITHMETIC CALCULATOR")
print("----------------")
print("[1] - Addition")
print("[2] - Subtraction")
print("[3] - Multiplication")
print("[4] - Division")
print("----------------")

choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
first_num(num1)
sec_num(num2)

if choice == '1':
    sum = first_num(num1) + sec_num(num2)
    print("The sum is: ")
```

I just wanted to ask if it is possible, and if so, how?

Comment: return them from your functions - `return num1`

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to `return` the number you asked for, and you need to assign the result to a variable at the time that you call it.  Since you can call a function any number of times, you don't need to define a unique function for each number.

```
def get_num(label):
    return int(input(f"Enter {label} number: "))


print("ARITHMETIC CALCULATOR")
print("----------------")
print("[1] - Addition")
print("[2] - Subtraction")
print("[3] - Multiplication")
print("[4] - Division")
print("----------------")

choice = input("Enter your choice: ")
num1 = get_num("first")
num2 = get_num("second")

if choice == '1':
    print(f"The sum is: {num1 + num2}")
```

```
ARITHMETIC CALCULATOR
----------------
[1] - Addition
[2] - Subtraction
[3] - Multiplication
[4] - Division
----------------
Enter your choice: 1
Enter first number: 31
Enter second number: 11
The sum is: 42
```